# Odoo database login issue?

Tags: database, postgresql, webforms, odoo, odoo-8

I have multiple databases running on a Odoo server , however for some reason I cannot log in to a specific database . The issue is when I enter the user name and password credential  , the page refreshes , even if I deliberately try to enter a wrong user name and password the page just refreshes as well . I have checked both the server logs  and Postgres database and no error appears when I try to login  .

Ways I have tried to solve the issue  :

- I have removed the add-ons path with the custom modules that could
  have caused the issue and restarted the Odoo server and still I
  cannot login.
- I have also dropped the database , reimported the database SQL file
  and tried to log in but still no prevail .
- I moved the custom module source code(that could be the cause of the
  problem ) and the same database down to a local machine and
  everything was fine I could login.

Has any one come across this type of issue before or knows what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have value for some parameters in config files ? Check these parameters :

- --no-database-list
- --db-filter
- --log-db

Comment: hey thanks for the response , yes i have the db-filter parameter in the config file : dbfilter = .*

Answer (score 0):

You can choose database before login by following link :

http://localhost:8079/web/database/selector

Just replace your IP and port, you will have one drop-down for selecting your database.

If you don't find your database in that drop down you should check config file for database filter.

If you find any filter there , **Remove it**, Again try with above link.